# Blazor load file js menu

Tags: javascript, blazor

I bought Vuexy html template on themeforest. I then added html functionality to the website built on the Blazor system.

Now the functions are working fine, only the nav menu is not working the way I want it to.

Image according to the html template I bought

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4Sx9.png)

And here is the image after I added Blazor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wgu4G.png)

As you can see, the browser gives an error

```
app-menu.js:82 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stop' of null
     at app-menu.js:82


setTimeout(function () {
        $.app.menu.container.stop().animate(
          {
            scrollTop: change
          },
          300
        );
        $('.main-menu').data('scroll-to-active', 'false');
      }, 300);
    }
```

I have tried many ways but can't fix it. Hope you all can help me

Comment: Does anyone know it? Help me
I don't know how to handle it

Comment: Hi, Were you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

workaround..

MainLayout.razor

```
@code 
{
  [Inject]
  protected IJSRuntime JsRuntime { get; set; }

  protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
  {
    if (firstRender)
       JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("onBlazorReady");
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<script>
    var compactMenu = false;
    var onBlazorReady = () => {
        if (feather) {
            feather.replace({
                width: 14,
                height: 14
            });
        }

        if ($body.hasClass('menu-collapsed') || localStorage.getItem('menuCollapsed') === 'true') {
            compactMenu = true;
        }
        $.app.menu.init(compactMenu);
        $.app.nav.init({ speed: 300 });
    }
</script>
```

I do not know why. But this is how it works.

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.